# Laravel: How to select images from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

New to Laravel and can't seem to solve this otherwise trivial issue. Working with someone else's code here. They've defined the array "assets" in which 4 images are being pulled:

```
foreach(unserialize($productData['assets']) as $asset){
   if(in_array($asset->rel,$denyRel)){
        continue;
   }
    $assets[$i]['link'] = $asset->href;
    $assets[$i]['rel'] = $asset->rel;
   $i++;
}
```

The results from that are as followed:

```
 [assets] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [link] => http://test.images-amazon.com/images/I/image1L.jpg
                     [rel] => PT01
                 )

                 [1] => Array
                     (
                         [link] => http://test.images-amazon.com/images/I/image2L.jpg
                         [rel] => PT02
                     )

                 [2] => Array
                     (
                         [link] => http://test.images-amazon.com/images/I/image3L.jpg
                         [rel] => PT03
                     )

                 [3] => Array
                     (
                         [link] => http://test.images-amazon.com/images/I/image4L.jpg
                         [rel] => MAIN
                   ) 
            )

    )
```

To pull all of them I can execute the following foreach loop:

```
@foreach($assets as $asset)
    <div class="alt-img">
        <img src="{{$asset['link']}}" data-rel="{{$asset['rel']}}" alt="{{$pageTitle}}" data-altImage="{{$asset['link']}}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

However, I only need to pull specific ones from the array such as PT01 or PT02. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you. NOTE: Site is hosted through AWS and URLs have been modified slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Just select basing on your condition.
Say you want to keep only 'PT01' and 'PT02', you could do:

```
<?php $allowed = array('PTO1','OT02'); // This is just an example ?>

@foreach($assets as $asset)
  @if(in_array($asset['rel'], $allowed))
    <div class="alt-img">
        <img src="{{$asset['link']}}" data-rel="{{$asset['rel']}}" alt="{{$pageTitle}}" data-altImage="{{$asset['link']}}">
    </div>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

The above code will print only those images which have a `data-rel` (well, a `rel` index) of 'PTO1' and 'PT02'.
Basically, you're already looping, so just choose (according to the criterium you want) which one to print or not